# What is the meaning of the commands "clip" and "trim" during image insertion?

Tags: includegraphics, crop, clip, pdf-with-trim

I use the following command (taken on internet) to crop a .pdf image:

`\includegraphics[trim={0.0cm 4.0cm 0.0cm 4.0cm},clip,  scale=0.8,page=1,angle=90]{aircraft_attitude/Q3_project_scheme.pdf}`

I cannot understand the difference between them.
Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `trim` keyword affects the 'apparent size' of the image but does not in itself make any material invisible: anything outside of the trimmed border is simply overprinted with the surrounds. The `clip` keyword means that anything outside the apparent size should be hidden by the viewer: it's still possible to 'see' this content in the underlying PDF.

Comment: I always wondered if clipped material was still present in the underlying document.  Is that also true of `\clipbox` of the `trimclip` package?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, as the way this works is to include *all* of the content then use a clipping operation around it. You can't know in advance if some element crosses the boundary, e.g. a line that might get cut off.

Comment: I see your point, for non-pixelated content.